Why are all path-components in complete spaces analytic?
I was recently going over an article of Becker named "The Number of Path-Components of a Compact Subset of $\mathbb R^n$" and he states the fact above. I tried to prove it formally through projections but failed and I could not find any proof. Any help would be welcome - tips, links, thank you.

Related is How complicated can the path component of a compact metric space be? (mathoverflow), but the result you want a proof of is only stated (in a comment and in an answer), not proved (not even an indication of how to go about it).

You should give more information in your question and do not expect that readers make their own "research" in the linked paper. For example, what does analytic mean here?

Hint (when $X$ is Polish): Informally,  the path-component of $x\in X$ is the set of all $y\in X$ such that there exists a continuous path from $x$ to $y$. The set of all paths in $X$ is $C([0,1], X)$. If $X$ is a Polish space, then this space is Polish as well with the uniform metric (see Kechris, Classical Descriptive Set Theory, Theorem 4.19). Show that the set $\{(y,p)\in X\times C([0,1], X)\mid p(0)=x, p(1)=y\}$ is closed in  $ X\times C([0,1], X)$ with the product topology. The component of $x$ is the projection of this set to $X$.
